# Calculating total counts for specific items

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, calculation

I need a formula for calculating the counts of the items A,B,.. So that I get the total numbers.

You can view a preview here

[image: preview].

Any ideas how that formula could look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admitting the first A of your table is in B3, this will do! ;)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B$3:B$7=F3)*1,(C$3:C$7))
```

You can then drag down the formula.

Comment: What is the message? AND What are : the range of your table, the 1st cell that you want, the cell in which you put the formula for the 1st cell?

Comment: It says that there was an error in the formula... nothing else. Items: B19:B23 Counts: C19:C23. So I change it to "=SUMPRODUCT((B$19:B$23=F19)*1,(C$19:C$23))" and I did put the formula in G19

Comment: @drifter213 : Do you have Excel in English? Is `,` the separator that you usually use? Try pressing Ctrl+Shit+Enter to validate as array formula, but this should work without it. It's working fine on my computer... :/

Answer (score 0):

You already accepted the answer but frankly SUMPRODUCT as an array formula is overly complicated for this.  There is a built in [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) function that does exactly this.  You would use SUMIF formula like so:

```
=SUMIF($B$3:$B$7, F3, $C$3:$C$7)
```

If you have more than one criteria like one column has to be A and the other column has to be Apples, you would use [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) to enter in multiple criteria.  Much easier to read/understand, imo.